# CBPeripheral's discoverServices not returning anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect to a Bluetooth peripheral but it does not work to discover the services. When the device is discovered I print the advertisement data and it shows the following:

```
{
    kCBAdvDataChannel = 38;
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = UR;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        1802
    );
}
```

As you can see, there is clearly a service advertised. However, after connection I use the following code:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    DDLogInfo(@"Connected to %@", peripheral.name);
    [self.bluetoothManager stopScan];
    if (peripheral == self.connectedPeripheral && self.connectedPeripheral.state ==  CBPeripheralStateConnected){
        [self.connectedPeripheral setDelegate:self];
        [self.connectedPeripheral discoverServices:nil];
    }
}
```

However `- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error` never gets called. I also made sure to make a breakpoint on `didDisconnectPeripheral` just in case it gets disconnected for some reason but it does not seem to make any difference.

The same issue appears if I use `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:` with the UDID of the service mentioned earlier, it won't display any results.

The device I'm trying to connect to is a Mac which is publishing its service using `IOBluetooth` to act as a peripheral.

Any idea on what could be wrong here?

Comment: When do you set `self.connectedPeripheral`? Does your code go through your `if` test?

Comment: In `centralManager: didDiscoverPeripheral`. It was just a precaution to make sure it doesn't get deallocated which I got an error for previously.
Yes, it goes through.

Comment: That's strange, I usually keep this peripheral when I enter into the `didConnectPeripheral`. Seems more appropriate. Try rebooting the iPhone.

Comment: I'll try moving that part of the code to there, see if it makes a difference. Tried with two separate iPhones.

Comment: I get this error if I don't save it prior to connection: `CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBPeripheral: 0x14e9db20 identifier = 79836C48-3513-F357-EC58-3C32181E2452, Name = "UR", state = connecting> is being dealloc'ed while pending connection`

Comment: You are correct, you need to save the connecting peripheral to a property to stop the warning about deallocation. Have you tried the LightBlue app?  It can scan for peripherals as well as act as a peripheral

Comment: Tried with LightBlue and it seems to get stuck on Reading Services. So I guess the issue is server side then, weird that it gets stuck however.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to have stemmed from the server implementation. Most likely due to things not being retained properly.